# ScrollView inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, scrollview, android-viewpager

So I have a `ScrollView` as the first view of a `ViewPager`. The following code renders correctly, but it simply does not scroll.

ShadeDisplay.java

```
public class ShadeDisplay extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle ParthMehrotra) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(getSherlockActivity());
        sv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        sv.setFillViewport(true);
        sv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getSherlockActivity());
        ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        ImageView iv = new ImageView(getSherlockActivity());
        iv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.banner);
        ll.addView(iv);

        Pattern patern1 = new Pattern(getSherlockActivity());
        patern1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        Pattern patern2 = new Pattern(getSherlockActivity());
        patern2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        ll.addView(patern1);
        ll.addView(patern2);

        sv.addView(ll);
        return sv;
    }

}
```

Pattern.java

```
public class Pattern extends View {

    Paint[] shade = new Paint[5];

    public Pattern(Context context) {
        super(context);

        for (int i = 0; i < shade.length; i++) {
            shade[i] = new Paint();
        }

        shade[0].setColor(Color.RED);
        shade[1].setColor(Color.BLUE);
        shade[2].setColor(Color.GREEN);
        shade[3].setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        shade[4].setColor(Color.CYAN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getWidth() / 3, shade[0]);
        canvas.drawRect(((getWidth() / 3) * 2), 0, getWidth(), getWidth(),
                shade[1]); 
        canvas.drawRect(0, ((getWidth() / 3) * 2), getWidth(), getWidth(),
                shade[2]);
        canvas.drawRect(0, (getWidth() / 3), getWidth()/3, getWidth(), 
                shade[3]);
        canvas.drawRect(getWidth() / 3, getWidth() / 3, ((getWidth() / 3) * 2),
                ((getWidth() / 3) * 2), shade[4]);

    }
}
```

I know I must be overlooking something really silly but I can't find the solution anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure there is enough content to scroll? What happens if you remove `sv.setFillViewport(true);`?

Comment: I just noticed something, the second Button, (test2) doesn't reach a height of 500, it behaves like a wrapcontent

Comment: You're calling `test1.setLayoutParams` instead of `test2.setLayoutParams`.

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me, I fixed it on the example for the buttons, and I updated my code to express what I'm really trying to do. Still no luck it doesn't scroll

Comment: What if you set a fixed height for the `Pattern`s? I feel like they will not take up the proper space since they are just canvas wrappers.

Comment: Yes, the same way you had for the `Button`s.

Comment: YES! Using
  Display display = this.getSherlockActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
  int w = display.getWidth();
  int h = display.getWidth();

Ended up doing the trick, Thanks!

Comment: I've added the solution as an answer--if you accept it, it will make it easier for others to find the answer, and will help you get better answers in the future. Glad everything is working now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be with your `Pattern`s. Since they are simply wrappers for a `Canvas`, they do not have any content to give them a height. Giving them fixed heights will ensure that all their content is shown, and will allow the `ScrollView` to account for this, and allow you to scroll properly.